# C# MVC4 WebSecurity.CurrentUserId inside RouteConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to retrieve the `int id = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` inside the `RouteConfig.cs`. The `id` is used in an entity framework so that I'll know which controller to limit the user by using `routes.IgnoreRoute()` but the `id` gives me a

```
System.NullReferenceException
```

I'm trying to use this instead of Attribute to avoid placing/misplacing it in each/some controller.

Comment: Related: [What is a `NullReferenceException` and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: it give you null because ruteConfig class get execute in App_start event that is the event fire once when first page request come and other thing is no user logged into system at that time

Answer (score 2):

Routes registration is performed early upon `Application_Start`. At this stage, `WebSecurity` is not initialized yet (and even if it were, it knows nothing about the current user because there is no `Request` yet), so you cannot use it this way.

If you insist relying on `WebSecurity` for routes resolving, you can use a `RouteConstraint` that will be checked upon actually *requesting* that route so you'll have an HTTP `Request` and authenticated / non-authenticated user in-tact.

For example:

```
public class CheckUserIdRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            return false;

        var userId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

        // check your user id
        return userId == 1;
    }
}
```

Then attach the constraint to your route registration. For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SomeRoute",
    url: "SomeRoute/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "MyCtrl", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { CheckUserId = new CheckUserIdRouteConstraint() }
);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've used a breakpoint aligned to `if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)` but when I start debugging the program it didn't stopped here.

Comment: @Aikitchi, I made a mistake in the constraint registration. The correct syntax is `constraints: new { CheckUserId = new CheckUserIdRouteConstraint() }`. See revised answer.